# Add item to Generic List / Collection using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to add an item to a Generic list using reflection. In the method "DoSomething", I am trying to finish the following line,

```
pi.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(??????)
```

but I am getting different kinds of error.

Below is my complete code

```
public class MyBaseClass
{        
    public int VechicleId { get; set; }        
}    
public class Car:MyBaseClass
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
}    
public class Bike : MyBaseClass
{
    public int CC { get; set; }
}        
public class Main 
{
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    public MyBaseCollection<Car> lstCar {get;set;}

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] p =this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in p)
        {
            if (pi.PropertyType.Name.Contains("MyBaseCollection"))
            {
                //Cln contains List<Car>
                IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> cln = pi.GetValue(this, null) as IEnumerable<MyBaseClass>;

                **//Now using reflection i want to add  a new car to my object this.MyBaseCollection**
                pi.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(??????)
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Any ideas / suggestion ?

Comment: What Type is MyBaseCollection? Is it similar to a List<T>? Not all classes that implement IEnumerable are guaranteed to have an Add method.

Comment: @JoeRobich: MyBaseCollection is own collection implementation which is derived from  IList<T> , Even answer for List<MyBaseClass> should solve my problem...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you want:

```
// Cast to IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> isn't helping you, so why bother?
object cln = pi.GetValue(this, null);

// Create myBaseClassInstance. 
// (How will you do this though, if you don't know the element-type?)
MyBaseClass myBaseClassInstance = ...

// Invoke Add method on 'cln', passing 'myBaseClassInstance' as the only argument.
pi.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(cln, new[] { myBaseClassInstance } );
```

Since you don't know what the element-type of the collection is going to be (could be Car, Bike, Cycle etc.) you're going to find it hard to find a useful cast. For example, although you say the collection will *definitely* implement `IList<SomeMyBaseClassSubType>`, that isn't all that helpful since `IList<T>` isn't covariant. Of course, casting to `IEnumerable<MyBaseClass>` *should* succeed, but that won't help you since it doesn't support mutations. On the other hand, if your collection-type implemented the non-generic `IList` or `ICollection` types, casting to those might come in handy.

But if you're *sure* that the collection will implement `IList<Car>` (i.e. you know the element-type of the collection beforehand), things are easier:

```
// A much more useful cast.
IList<Car> cln = (IList<Car>)pi.GetValue(this, null);

// Create car.
Car car = ...

// The cast helped!
cln.Add(car);
```

Comment: Adding item to IList will definitely work out but in my case i need to type cast to IEnumerable bcos..i have a base class for generic type.. " IList<Car> cln = (IList<Car>)pi.GetValue(this, null); " ...so your first suggestion worked out.... (i'm converting to ienumerable for other coding requirements)

Comment: Ques: // (How will you do this though, if you don't know the element-type?)
Answer: I get values from different place in the object hierarchy...., Not creating derived class at runtime..Above code is sample for stackoverflow prupose..(real time it's  more complex.)

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative... Just don't; consider the non-generic IList interface:

```
IList list = (IList) {... get value ...}
list.Add(newItem);
```

While it isn't *obligatory* for all generic collections to implement IList, they pretty much all do, since it underpins such a lot of core framework code.

Comment: I did mention this, but I think the OP's collection class is his/her own. In this case, it's doubtful the non-generic interface has been implemented. :)

Answer (score 0):

start with `typeof<List<>>.GetMethods`, you do not invoke a method of the property, but a method of the type of the property

Answer (score 0):

Could you just avoid reflection all together and use:

```
List<MyBaseClass> lstCar { get; set; }

lstCar.Add((MyBaseClass)new Car());
```

You could also consider using an interface or abstract methods...

Comment: I need some generic way, Above code is just sample..in real time i need it for many pruposes

Comment: You should be able to overcome this with inheritance, I personally think that the use of reflection would be unnecessary if the classes and sub-classes were structured correctly.